# Why does "$|E|^2 \propto $ the number of photons" follow from "$\epsilon_{photon} = hf$"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, quantum-optics, intensity

For my introduction to quantum physics course we are using the book "University Physics volume 3", availabe [here](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-3/pages/7-1-wave-functions), in the linked chapter in the first paragraph of the "Using the wave function" heading, the following is stated

> The energy of an individual photon depends only on the frequency of light, $\epsilon_{photon} = hf$, so $|E|^2$  is proportional to the number of photons

$|E|$ here refers to the energy density of a light wave at a specific point in space and time.

I cannot find any context which explains why the second statement follows from the first and it appears that we are just expected to take this at face value. I am not satisfied just accepting that this there supposedly exists some reasoning that takes us from

> The energy of an individual photon depends only on the frequency of light, $\epsilon_{photon} = hf$

to

> $|E|^2$  is proportional to the number of photons

since I believe my understanding of this second statement will be greatly improved if I can understand how it follows from the primer.

So that is what I am asking how and through what reasoning does the fact that "The energy of an individual photon depends only on the frequency of light, $\epsilon_{photon} = hf$" lead to the conclusion that "$|E|^2$  is proportional to the number of photons"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|E|^2$ here actually means "square of the electric field", not "square of the energy density."

In vacuum, it turns out that the energy density of the electromagnetic field is proportional to $|E|^2$.$^\star$ Since the energy density of the field should be the number of photons in the field$^\dagger$ times the energy of one photon, we have $|E|^2$ is proportional to $\epsilon$.

---

$^\star$ Footnote for the pedantic: In general the energy density is proportional to $|E|^2+|B|^2$, but for plane waves in vacuum and in units where $c=1$, $|E|=|B|$, so we can say in vacuum the energy density is proportional to $|E|^2$.

$^\dagger$ Footnote the super pedantic: yes, I know the number of photons in the field may not be a well-defined concept in general.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence you quote, the "only" is more important than the actual equation for photon energy. For photons of a given frequency, the energy flux through a given area is therefore proportional to the photon flux.

From classical electromagnetism, the energy flux in vacuo is proportional to $\overline {E^2}$. Hence the textbook's claim.